# Change the spacing between characters | Word API JavaScript

Tags: fonts, ms-word, office-js, spacing

I need a modified distance between the characters in a word, that is, to make the word **Extended**. I found the closest analogue in Visual Basic for Applications: [`Font.Spacing`](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/office/vba/api/word.font.spacing). I need to know if this can be implemented using the Word API.

[Explanation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aECbw.png)

Comment: No, this is not (yet) implemented in the Word JS API.

Best you could do would be to apply the formatting directly using OOXML.

Comment: @CindyMeister Please make your comment an answer, so the question will count as answered in SO stats. Thanks.

Comment: Done, @RickKirkham :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is unfortunately not (yet) implemented in the Word JS API.

What you could do would be to apply the formatting directly using the OOXML methods for the `Range` object.

You can research the necessary Word Open XML by opening a sample document with the formatting applied in the Open XML SDK Productivity Tool.

[This article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/word/create-better-add-ins-for-word-with-office-open-xml) explains how to use it in your add-in.